# Fetching data from sql databse in flutter datewise?

Tags: sql, flutter, android-sqlite, android-database, sqflite

I am making an app in flutter and I am implementing SQL database using the sqflite plugin. In this app, users can create transactions by filling out the form below [image: form]
Then the user can verify their transactions and they also will be having an option to edit the transaction in case they have made a mistake [image: viewscreen]
Now I want to add a feature by which they can get the sum of expenses they have done in a particular month on this screen below[image: monthwise]
It is showing null but it should show the sum of the expenses

The code for my query is

```
Future getDataJan() async{
final db = await database;
sumJan=await db.rawQuery(
    'SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES WHERE DATE(DATETIME) >= ? AND DATE(DATETIME) <= ?',
    [2021-01-01, 2021-01-31] ).then(Sqflite.firstIntValue);
print(sumJan);
finalJan=sumJan.toString();
}
```

Database creation:

```
Future<Database> createDatabase() async {
String dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();

return await openDatabase(
  join(dbPath, 'expenseDB.db'),
  version: 1,
  onCreate: (Database database, int version) async {
    print("Creating expense table");

    await database.execute(
      "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_EXPENSES ("
      "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
      "$COLUMN_NAME TEXT,"
      "$COLUMN_AMOUNT INTEGER,"
      "$COLUMN_UNNECESSARYEXPENSES INTEGER,"
      "$COLUMN_CATEGORY TEXT,"
      "$COLUMN_DATETIME TEXT"
      ")",
    );
  },
);
}
```

Mapping Database(I think it's not working because of string while mapping):

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
var map = <String, dynamic>{
  DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_NAME: name,
  DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_AMOUNT: amount,
  DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_UNNECESSARYEXPENSES: isUnnecessaryExpenses ? 1 : 0,
  DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_CATEGORY: category,
  DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_DATETIME: pickedDate,
};

if (id != null) {
  map[DatabaseProvider.COLUMN_ID] = id;
}

return map;
}
```

Entries of database:
[image: databaseEntry]

Edit:
This is my code for creating a Widget to call for datepicking:

```
  Widget DatePicker() {

   showDatePicker(context: context, initialDate: DateTime.now(), firstDate: DateTime.parse("2020-01-01 00:00:01Z"), lastDate: DateTime.now()
  ).then((value){
    if (value == null){
      return;
     }
     _dateTime = value;
     ////saving in string
     pickedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(_dateTime);
     });
   }
```

Error given after the suggestion by  Problematic Dude :

```
lib/db/database_provider.dart:111:59: Error: Expected ',' before this.
  'SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES WHERE strftime('%m' , date(datetime)) ==   01').then(Sqflite.firstIntValue);
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    lib/db/database_provider.dart:111:58: Error: The getter 'm' isn't defined  for the class 'DatabaseProvider'.
    - 'DatabaseProvider' is from 'package:finance_manager/db /database_provider.dart' ('lib/db/database_provider.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a   getter or field named 'm'.
  'SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES WHERE strftime('%m' , date(datetime)) == 01').then(Sqflite.firstIntValue);
                                                     ^
   lib/db/database_provider.dart:111:57: Error: The operator '%' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
   Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '%' operator.
  'SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES WHERE strftime('%m' , date(datetime)) ==   01').then(Sqflite.firstIntValue);
                                                    ^
  lib/db/database_provider.dart:111:59: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'.
- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
     'SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES WHERE strftime('%m' , date(datetime)) == 01').then(Sqflite.firstIntValue);
```

**Update**

I opened the database using database inspector in android studio and tried running the following queries in it:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES

SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES WHERE DATE(DATETIME) >= 2021-01-01 and  DATE(DATETIME) <= 2021-01-31
```

**The above query works perfectly fine and returns the sum of the column amount**, but as soon as I run the second query it gives me null again, I think I am saving the date in the wrong manner.

Please help.

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Can you show how you are converting dateTime to string  for storing it in DB?

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, I have added the code for it please check it once again.

Comment: Try executing this `SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES WHERE strftime('%m' , date(datetime)) == 01`

Comment: I have implemented it like this:                                                                                                Future getDataJan() async{
    final db = await database;
    sumJan=await db.rawQuery(
      'SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES WHERE strftime('%m' , date(datetime)) == 01').then(Sqflite.firstIntValue);
    print(sumJan);
    finalJan=sumJan.toString();
  }

Comment: I have posted the error message in question

Comment: You need to use escape char

Comment: I am new in flutter can you please explain?

Comment: `WHERE DATE(DATETIME) >= '2021-01-01' and  DATE(DATETIME) <= '2021-01-31'` you are missing single quotes around the dates.

Comment: Yeah @forpas that works but can you please tell me how can I implement this in my function which I am creating.

Comment: I can't help you with Flutter, but try by adding single quotes around the dates here: `['2021-01-01', '2021-01-31']`. Note that the dates in your table must have the format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is missing quotes around date

```
Future getDataJan() async{
final db = await database;
sumJan=await db.rawQuery(
    'SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES WHERE DATE(DATETIME) >= ? AND DATE(DATETIME) <= ?',
    ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-31'] ).then(Sqflite.firstIntValue);
print(sumJan);
finalJan=sumJan.toString();
}
```